# Java Annotations Member Validation on Compilation

Tags: java

I have a custom java annotation like below

```
@customelement(folder = "/path/")
public testMethod() {

}
```

I want to validate the folder path ("/path/") for the folder member variable and report error inside java source. How I can do that?

Comment: When do you like to report a error?

Comment: when compiling this class

Comment: This is not possible. Sorry!

Comment: Is it possible by any means, other than compilation phase?

Comment: You can do this at runtime, but you need a instance of the Class. OR you write a plugin for your build-management-tool.

Comment: I know I can do it at runtime, by processing the annotation.. But I need this <folder = "/path/"> to be validated at compilation time. If this is possible..

Comment: Whatfor? Deveopment-PC != Customer's-PC.

Comment: This is for Development

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61114/discussion-between-peter-rader-and-sandip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Java Annotation Element Method return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831033/java-annotation-element-method-return)

```
   @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, 
                           RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        Set<? extends Element> elements = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(CustomAnnotation.class);
        for(Element te : elements){
          CustomAnnotation annotation = te.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
          String folder = annotation.folder();
          //... do sth with folder in context of te. 
          //te represent annotated method, e.g. testMethod from your example
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Also remember to annotate your CompileTimeAnnotationProcessor with @SupportedAnnotationTypes("package.CustomAnnotation") and @SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_7) (or whatever version of Java syntax are you going to support).

In case of further problems, I recommend to read this great tutorial blog post.