# Java Annotation Element Method return

Tags: java

I have a custom annotation like below.

```
@customelement(folder = "/path/")
public testMethod() {

}
```

How I can extract folder value i.e."/path/", using AbstractProcessor, below?

```
public class CompileTimeAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, 
                           RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        Set<? extends Element> elements = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(CustomAnnotation.class);
        for(Element te : elements){
          for (Element e : te.getEnclosedElements()) {
                     if (e.getSimpleName().toString().equals("folder")) {
                       //Here fetch method return value
                  }
           }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom annotation processor, or do you want to read the values reflectively at runtime?  If it's the former, how are you compiling it?  I've only ever seen/used an annotation processor when compiling source using [`JavaCompiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).

Comment: @Makoto you can run javac compiler with proper arguments (see: -proc, -processorpath, -s, -processor) to enable and configure annotation processing during standard javac compilation. I think this is a typical way of using annotation processors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you want to do sth like:

```
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, 
                           RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        Set<? extends Element> elements = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(CustomAnnotation.class);
        for(Element te : elements){
          CustomAnnotation annotation = te.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
          String folder = annotation.folder();
          //... do sth with folder in context of te. 
          //te represent annotated method, e.g. testMethod from your example
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Also remember to annotate your `CompileTimeAnnotationProcessor` with `@SupportedAnnotationTypes("package.CustomAnnotation")` and
    `@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_7)` (or whatever version of Java syntax are you going to support).

In case of further problems, I recommend to read [this great tutorial blog post](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/).

Comment: Thanks.. This helps. How I can get the source file info and project name inside AbstractProcessor?